# Eclipse Content Assist, always change to incorrect code after hitting space

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist

I have a problem with auto complete function in eclipse. Whenever I type code after hitting <kbd>space</kbd> button, the code changed automatically.

---

#### Here the example

[code before I hit space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV9uP.png)
[public automatically become Public_Member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4EFU.png)

---

To solve that, after typing code I press <kbd>esc</kbd> button, then after that press <kbd>space</kbd>. But it waste my time especially when I forgot to hit <kbd>esc</kbd>, I have to manually delete the incorrect code and write it back again.

How to solve this <kbd>space</kbd> problem? Without disabling content assist or reverting it back to default?

Comment: Java does not allow to define a method directly inside a method. At this location the keyword `public` is incorrect in contrast to the items proposed by the content assist. Maybe you forgot `}` to close the `main` method before `public void cry(){ ... }` (and `cry();{` should be `cry(){`).

Comment: somehow I already solved it. but the problem is not in **cry();{ }** (sorry I typing code so fast. that I made mistake). I forgot how to solve the problem, but its around window-->preference --> java